# Подскажите IDE для С++. Для линукса

Tags: c++, linux, ide

Среда разработки должна подсказывать или выделять ошибки на этапе написания кода, до компиляции.

Comment: Такой себе холиварный вопрос. NetBeans, Code::Block, CLion, QtCreator.

Comment: А что значит "для Линукса"? Linux - целевая платформа? Или Linux - и платформа повседневной интерактивной разработки тоже? Во-первых, современный Visual Studio (2017) поддерживает удаленную разработку на Linux (через ssh). Во-вторых, львиная доля прикладной разработки для Linux делается в Visual Studio под Windows. В таком случае на Linux делается лишь чистовая компиляция и QA.

Comment: Била Гейтса попросите, пусть порт сделает.

Comment: AnT, "для линукса", имею ввиду как инструмента для создания ПО в целом, не имеет значения под какую ОС пишется ПО

Comment: AnT, спасибо ваш за комментарий. Я обратила внимание на то, чего раньше не замечала.

Comment: Через ssh надо будет попробовать в линуксе VS.

Comment: Знакомый прогер советует `KDevelop`.

Comment: ... и говорят, что при использовании Visual Studio в режиме Linux разработки в качестве Linux-хоста может выступать Linux-subsystem на той же самой Windows 10 машине, на которой запускается сама Visual Studio (однако я сам не пробовал).

Comment: Есть опасение, что в скором времени этот вопрос могут удалить, т.к. не соответствует тематике StackOverflow. Приведите его хотя бы в соответствие с [критериями метки "поиск-программ"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC/info).

Comment: Спасибо. Qt и KDevelop подходят. Не понятно, почему этот вопрос требует правки. Ну да ладно.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Много лет использую KDevelop. Достоинства:

1. Подчёркивает ошибку в момент набора (это Вам нужно?)
2. Показывает ссылки на определения и использование идентификаторов
3. Подкючает Help по разным библиотекам и прочему
4. Имеет возможность использовать заготовки кода
5. Свёртывает/развёртывает код по блокам
6. Поиск по файлу или всем файлам проекта
7. Подсветка синтаксиса по чёртовой пропасти разных языков
8. Автоматическая "раскраска" идентификаторов, котрая позволяет их легко искать

Ну, это то, что обеспечивает РЕДАКТОР этой IDE. Но, с моей точки зрения, гораздо более важно, что KDevelop поддерживает:

9. Проекты. В том числе - с подпроектами
10. Взаимодействие с make, cMake и Doxygen-ом
11. Интегрированный отладчик - очень мощный.
12. Элементаную настройку кросс-компилляции
13. И много ещё чего другого...

Например, для С++ есть просмотр дерева классов, быстрая навигация по ним и т.д...

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте **IDE** от [JetBrains CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/)

Comment: Однако, она стоит денег.

Comment: давайте на чистоту, очень мало тех кто покупает

Comment: @jashka, если бы мало кто покупал, то её бы не разрабатывали, не так ли? 200$ в год для разработчика деньги не большие, а если только CLion нужен и того меньше.

Answer (score -1):

Бери Qt. И код подчеркивает, и подсказывает, автодополнение кода есть, и пицу может заказать если что...))
[скачать](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/)

Comment: Возможно, вы имели ввиду QtCreator

Comment: спасибо большое